# Angular Router Wildcard URL not working with empty path

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I defined APP structure with this guide https://github.com/mathisGarberg/angular-folder-structure and in my main router file I do the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ContentLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            ...CustomerRouting
        ],
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    { path: 'app', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '', canActivate: [LegacyRedirectGuard]}
];

export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
});
```

I'm expecting that when I will visit unknown url, wildcard route call `LegacyRedirectGuard` that redirects us to external website or 404 page. But this is never happens, because `path: ''` catching everything.

`CustomerRouting` is just a nested list of routes.

Comment: You should probably remove the `redirectTo` from your `**` path, it may kick in even before the route guard and that why you only get the `''` route.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your `RedirectGard` Looks like, but this is how I would implement it:

**RedirectGuard TS**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

      window.location.href = 'https://yourlink.com' + state.url;
      return true;
  }
}
```

**Make sure to import it in app.module:**

`providers: [RedirectGuard]`

**routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ContentLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            ...CustomerRouting
        ],
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    { path: 'app', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: RedirectGuard, canActivate: [RedirectGuard]}
];
```

Comment: But I need to catch for example `/customer/` and load page component for it. But for example /not_existing_route/ catch with `**`

Comment: I just edited my reply, let me know if doing so help you catch unknown URL and redirecting them to an external site.

Comment: My problem that router never call `RedirectGuard`. Even if I will try to visit `unknown/url` it stays on `` path. When I remove `{
        path: '',
        component: ContentLayoutComponent,`
then it works fine. But I can't do that...

Comment: What I'm trying to achive - that from API I receive old legacy website links. And they are relative. I want to check - if router can't handle that link - go to the same link but on external legacy website

Comment: if I understand you correctly, I just edited my answer code to perform what you want to do. See the RedirectTS and routingTS edits